# forking a python process after loading TensorFlow

Tags: python, fork, tensorflow

`tf.Session()` is not `fork` safe which means that the behavior of the system after forking a process while `TensorFlow` is loaded into the memory is unknown.

is there any work around for sharing multiple devices (on a single machine), between multiple processes?

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to share a TensorFlow runtime between multiple processes is to use the [distributed TensorFlow support](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/distributed/index.html#distributed-tensorflow), which also works on a single machine.

In one process, you can start a server by running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
print server.target  # for other processes to connect
server.join()
```

This process will own all of the devices on the machine, by default.

In the other processes, you can create `tf.Session` objects that connect to the server:

```
sess = tf.Session("grpc://localhost:...")  # Use value of `server.target`.
```

These sessions can be used just like in-process sessions.

Comment: thank you for the answer. one side question though: this still wouldn't work with python builtin `multiprocessing` library since all the processes would be forks of each other and the TF (i.e. cuda) context would be shared between them? am I right on this?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to be careful to fork the subprocesses *before* creating the server, because that is what initializes the CUDA driver.

Comment: thanks again. by _creating the server_ you mean `tf.train.Server.create_local_server()` or just `import tensorflow` initializes the CUDA driver?

Comment: I believe `import tensorflow` only loads the driver libraries, and the initialization only happens at the first `tf.Session()` creation, but I'm not 100% sure if the process is safe to fork between those points.